# Why is not page redirected to edit.jsp?

Tags: java, liferay

My code is as follows:-

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editGreetingURL">
<portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/urldemo/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= editGreetingURL %>" method="POST"> 

<aui:input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</aui:form>
```

On clicking submit I am not redirected to edit.jsp..Why?

Comment: Why do you want to use an action URL for redirecting to a jsp when you can use an render URL?

Comment: i tried renderURL instead of actionURL and the problem is solved.

Comment: Nice to know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the main tags in Liferay if you want to become a professional. :D

First of all, you should understand the portlet's lifecycle. You can google it easily.

`<portlet:actionURL` calls *action* phase of your portlet.

`<portlet:renderURL` calls *render* phase of your portlet.

So, when you try to do this:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editGreetingURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/urldemo/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

you try to call action method which is not defined correctly yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<aui:form action="<%= editGreetingURL.toString() %>" method="POST">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.